# Parceljs webp converter

Tags: webp, parceljs

Is there any chance to convert images (*jpg*, *png*, ...) to *webp* format in **Parceljs** ? I can't find any **Parceljs** plugin for this action.

Answer (score 1):

For parcel v1 i also couldn't find a way.

For parcel v2 it should be planned, but its still beta and i couldn't get it to work with 2.0.0-beta.1.

**Update:**
Got it working with latest nightly build.

Here is my upgrade path:

```
npm uninstall parcel-bundler
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install sharp parcel@^2.0.0-nightly -D
```

It's described here: https://v2.parceljs.org/recipes/image/

In index.html i added a picture element:

```
<picture>
  <source src="url:./img/image.png?as=webp&width=350" type="image/webp" />
  <img src="url:./img/image.png?width=350" alt="..." width="350px" height="263px"/>
</picture>
```